# Django Get Auth User pk to be saved in model after form submission

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am currently implementing Django's Auth Users. I am now attempting to create a form with two simple fields with the User's pk as the foreign key. For the model I have the following code for the ForeignKey:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I then have a form class `(forms.ModelForm)` where I set the fields. I do not list the user field from the above model because I want that to be completed automatically when the user submits them form.

Finally, I have a view with the following post method:

```
    def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        sub = form.save(commit=False)

        sub.save()

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        sub = form.save(commit=False)
        sub.user = request.user
        sub.save()

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

and make sure this view only can asked by authenticated user